# django complex query for interdependant tables

Tags: python, django, list, django-models

Django Models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name


class ProductDetails(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    mfg = models.DateTimeField()
    exp = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.batch


class product_barcode(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
    flag = models.IntegerField()

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.barcode
```

I want to calculate number of barcodes generated by company_name

I tried some some code like

```
w=Product.objects.all().filter(company_name="company name")
print "w>>>",w
pid = []
for Pdata in w:
    pid.append(Pdata.id)
print "pid>>>",pid
```

Here I find ids of product name which belong to a specific company but after that I want to find batch codes(at ProductDetails) that belong to product ids, after that I need to count all barcodes that belong to batch codes.

in simple words

1. company ['company name']
2. products ['product1','product2','product3'] where company = 'company name'
3. Batch codes where products = ['product1','product2','product3']

   - product1 ['bxyz','b2xyz','b3xyz']
   - product2 ['b1xyz','b4xyz','b3xyz']
   - product3 ['b9xyz','b6xyz','b3xyz']
4. count Barcodes where batch codes ['bxyz','b2xyz','b3xyz']['b1xyz','b4xyz','b3xyz']['b9xyz','b6xyz','b3xyz']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, I understand well what you wanna do so what about something like:

```
count = product_barcode.objects.filter(batch__product__company_name='company name').count()
```

This should return number of barcodes for all products where company name is equal to 'company name'.

Two underscores are used for joining tables, like using JOIN in SQL. Based on [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should change name of the barcode class (`ProductBarcode`). It is really better start with it for the future.